# Why does 'apt-file list' list *.so files that arn't on the host? And which one do I link to?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker-errors

I've ran the following command to list the openssl library files on disk:

```
apt-file list libssl-dev
```

And got the output:

```
(a long list of *.h files)  
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
(.pc, .gz and others)
```

But the libssl.a and libssl.so arn't on the disk.

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl*
```

Gives this output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 328128 Feb  5  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 426232 Jun 20 05:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 433760 Jun 20 04:29 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
```

So how do I link to the ssl library in my C++ applications?  When I specify -llibssl.so, I get an error telling me its not found.

If I'm supposed to pick one of the existing files on disk, which one do I pick and what criteria do I use?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the develop package `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the issue?  I'd like to understand what's going on, and how other programs work without there being a libssl.so file on the system.  Does each user of the program I'm building which uses the library need to also install libssl-dev?

Comment: Because the SONAME is libssl.so.X.X, libssl.so is only a symbol link to libssl.so.X.X and is only needed at link-time, that's why the library were divide into develope package `libsslX.X-dev`, runtime package `libsslX.X`.

$ `readelf -d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 | grep SONAME`
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libssl.so.1.1]